# Recommended format for a large embedded stop motion animation on website?

Tags: file-formats, stop-motion

I have a stop motion animation of about 35 seconds in duration (~150 frames). The resolution is quite large at around 900px x 450px.

What is the best format to play this looping on my website? I think my options are either .gif, standard .swf, or convert it into a movie .swf.

What is the recommended approach to this? I want the images to have a high fidelity and I was hoping to not use flash due to Apple incompatibility.

Comment: I think that's too big for a .gif, so some sort of movie is probably the best answer. You don't necessarily need to use Flash--there are a number of JavaScript players that use HTML5: look at [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/).

Answer (score 2):

Likely the best solution is take your frames into a video editor, set the still pix time to about 0.23 sec for each shot as you indicated you wanted to show 150 frames in 35 seconds.
35 / 150 = 0.233333333

Set your project properties to 720p, (720 x 1280 progressive)
As you have 2:1 aspect ratio there will be some letter boxing.

Or a better match maybe to use iFrame format:
960 horizontal by 540 vertical pixels assuming you are using iMovie of FCP.

Assuming iMovie, render to .mov and follow these instructions to make it a .swf movie:
http://www.ehow.com/how_8245141_export-imovie-swf.html

Comment: It would also be possible to just upload the video to a video-sharing site e.g. Vimeo or YouTube and then just embed the video in his website.